# Why does it take time for absorption to set in?

Tags: optics, absorption

I read [this sentence](https://books.google.com/books?id=d8QU7tbzLKwC&lpg=PA57&ots=_uyPU5R9IF&dq=For%20a%20pulse%20since%20it%20takes%20some%20time%20for%20absorption%20to%20set%20in%20the%20trailing%20edge%20of%20a%20pulse%20is%20excessively%20absorbed.&pg=PA57#v=onepage&q=For%20a%20pulse%20since%20it%20takes%20some%20time%20for%20absorption%20to%20set%20in%20the%20trailing%20edge%20of%20a%20pulse%20is%20excessively%20absorbed.&f=false) in Optics Principles and Applications by Sharma regarding light dispersion:

> But since it takes some time for the absorption to set in, the trailing edge of the pulse is excessively absorbed.

With this associated figure:
[image: Context Image]

Why does it take time for absorption to set in?